# Copy excel values to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy a range of excel cells to another sheet every time the source values change?

---

This code below is working to copy and append on the next sheet. It needs 2 things:

1. execute when value in sheet 1 refreshes
2. paste special the values only on sheet 2

Thanks

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("metrics.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("metrics.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably using the `Worksheet_Calculate` event but your question needs more detail in order to propose an answer. See [ask].

Comment: Hi BigBen, I have a list of values that are refreshing in real time, I want to record all the values to a new sheet and keep appending them as they update. 

Lets say column A has the description, and B has the values. And the total range of the source is A1:B30
I want to copy this range to a new sheet everytime there is a change in B column. My vba skills are quite limited at this point. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Where are these values from? How are they being refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `Worksheet_TableUpdate` for this use. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.tableupdate).